# Why doesn't liquid vaporize in PD pumps during suction lift?

Tags: fluid-mechanics

I recently came across a discussion with my fellow colleague regarding the ability of Positive displacement pumps to self-prime. The reason for self priming was stated that PD pumps create suction lift (kind of vacuum) which pulls the liquid into pump.

Wouldn't this situation vaporize the liquid (create cavitation) since the liquids vaporize at lower pressure?

Comment: It all depends on the amount of pressure reduction for lift and the liquid's vapor pressure. at the operating temperature.

Comment: Any pump that can pump air without leaking or destroying itself is self priming. Whether the pump is sucking air or water doesn't change the height that water can be lifted. So basically I'm saying self priming and maximum lift are not related.

Answer (score 0):

Some pumps are desined to work with a negative suction head, others require a positive suction head.

There is a maximum suction head for any fluid so if the height the fluid has to be moved is greater than that then it can be done in stages or the pump is fitted at the bottom so it "pushes » the fluid. That means that the maximum output head must be considered.